# django 1.4 local admin images 404

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django 1.4, in my local development admin, when I upload an image for a model with an ImageField, the url to the uploaded file resolves to a 404.

My settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '%s/../public/media/' % os.path.dirname(__file__)
MEDIA_URL = 'http://mysite.dev:8000/media/'
```

Images in admin have a path of http://mysite.dev:8000/images/image.jpg

How do I show images uploaded in the local admin?

Comment: Why don't you wrap MEDIA_ROOT in quotes? It should not even start with this code. And what URL do images have after upload? And what is the handler for it in `urls.py`?

Comment: I updated the question.  I do not have a handler for images in urls.py.  I'm new to django, so I'm wasn't aware that would be necessary.

Comment: set up your settings.py like so http://pastebin.com/v4sn1fF9

Comment: Also, read `serving static files` in official docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is not meant to serve images, your HTTP server will (should, in production, anyway), hence the 404. BUT you can ask django to serve for your image in dev, as [this other SO subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451352/cant-figure-out-serving-static-images-in-django-dev-environment) explains in details.